# JSF 2.0 entity manager Transaction problems during render phase

Tags: hibernate, transactions, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

When rendering the final view during the render phase, hibernate throws

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role
```

And I suppose this is because there is no transaction to fetch lazy data.

In this case what is the best possible solution either than eagerly loading the data.

can I extend the transaction to cover this phase

NB. I'm not using EJBs so dont have Container Managed Transactions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the Hibernate version you are using, you can enable the eager fetching for this particular query. If the version of Hibernate you are using does not supports that, you'll have to pre-fetch it manually, by calling "getRoles" before getting into the view. One last solution is to use the "open session in view" pattern: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView